# ASP.NET web page phamton loading

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, windows-server-2008

We have installed a web site written by others which is compiled with Visual Studio 2008 and hosted in Windows server 2008 R2.

The IIS connection timeout is set to 120 seconds.  But for some pages, the first page loading fails with HTTP 404 error but sequential refresh can bring the page up.  The same problem happens for some images which fail to load in web pages.  We are not very sure it is network related issue or hosting issue.  Anyone encountered this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the IIS logs to see if you can see the dead requests in there. If not then it's likely a network issue. If you can see them look in the event log for errors, likely IO related

Comment: thanks!  I have checked IIS logs.  It seems that when the page is not loaded, nothing can be logged there.  No error in event viewer either.  I assume it is network related now.